FCM Migration from legacy to V1 needed for Web Push?
I'm sending web push notifications to Google Chrome (which uses FCM endpoints). Are there any steps that need to be taken since Firebase will be removing FCM legacy APIs, or is this only affecting pushing notifications to apps?
This is an example subscription (fcm endpoint + keys) - taken from this question
{"endpoint":"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/dpH5lCsTSSM:APA91bHqjZxM0VImWWqDRN7U0a3AycjUf4O-byuxb_wJsKRaKvV_iKw56s16ekq6FUqoCF7k2nICUpd8fHPxVTgqLunFeVeB9lLCQZyohyAztTH8ZQL9WCxKpA6dvTG_TUIhQUFq_n",
"keys": {
    "p256dh":"BLQELIDm-6b9Bl07YrEuXJ4BL_YBVQ0dvt9NQGGJxIQidJWHPNa9YrouvcQ9d7_MqzvGS9Alz60SZNCG3qfpk=",
    "auth":"4vQK-SvRAN5eo-8ASlrwA=="
    }
}


If you are using the standard Push API you don't need to do anything. If you are using a proprietary FCM API you may need to update...

When the user allows the notification in the permission pop-up, we get the web push subscription from the browser (like the example I attached) and we use it to push notifications

Did you find out if this is needed? I am in the same boat
